# PivotTableUpdate doesn't seem to work with only 1 line in a pivot

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I am trying to update a pivot table when selecting a field on a slicer. It works quite good...

...until there's due to a selection only 1 line in my pivot. Then it doesn't trigger anything anymore.

In the sheet code I have this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
' MsgBox "The PivotTable connection has been updated."
End Sub
```

It works flawlessly until the pivot only has 1 line left. After that it doesn't trigger anymore.

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Do you receive any kind of error message ?

Comment: No none. It just doesn't do anything.